# How to get SKU price with discounts for a specified user?

Tags: kentico

Could you tell me please, how to get SKU price with discounts for a specified user?

I work with Kentico from console application through C# API.

```
CMS.DataEngine.CMSApplication.Init();
var sku = SKUInfoProvider.GetSKUInfo(5069);
var price = SKUInfoProvider.GetSKUPrice(sku, null, true, false);
```

So, I want to apply user discounts for a price. I need to execute this method from specified user context, I guess.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: We use Kentico10. And now I have discovered the problem source:
ECommerceContext.CurrentShoppingCart is null in our console application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I thought, that I need to use context or something else. But no.
Code (C#):

```
if (CMS.DataEngine.CMSApplication.Init())
{
    SiteContext.CurrentSiteID = 1;
    var userInfo = UserInfoProvider.GetUserInfo("alexander@ulmaskulov.ru");
    var skuInfo = SKUInfoProvider.GetSKUInfo(5069);
    var cart = ShoppingCartFactory.CreateCart(new 
    SiteInfoIdentifier(SiteContext.CurrentSite.SiteID), userInfo);
    var price = SKUInfoProvider.GetSKUPrice(skuInfo, cart, true, false);
}
```